# delete macrium reflect backup image

Tags: backup, windows-10, hard-drive

I have recently made a backup of Windows 10 using Macrium Reflect v6.1; the backup consists of an image written to an external hard drive, following these "widely used" instructions:

http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-backup-windows-10-safe-way-with.html

For some reason I would now like to remove the image from the hard drive and format it, so as to be empty and consisting of only one partition again. In Win10, I tried to do so with the Disk Management, but to no avail since the partitions on the hard disc cannot be accessed/reformatted. Is there a Macrium build-in tool to remove images or any other tool to be recommended for this task? Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile, found a way. I run the Win10 build-in tool diskpart twice, using command clean (carefully!). After that, I could initialize, format and partiton the drive "as usual" with the Win Disk Management. With the drive having 4 TB memory, I had to use GPT as partition style to access it fully; with MBR style not all of the disk space could be accessed.

Comment: I am having the same issue! Could you please provide detailed instructions to follow? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: lack of time to do so, but (for the diskpart part) you may follow these instructions which i just found: http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/005929en.

Comment: Don't forget you can always use the forum and knowledgebase for help on such topics https://forum.macrium.com/Default.aspx http://knowledgebase.macrium.com/display/KNOW7/Macrium+Reflect+KnowledgeBase